# How to set the caption of a figure to the same indent as the title

Tags: latex

I am trying to make a caption to a figure that looks like this:

Figure 1: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text

or alternatively like this:

Figure 1:
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text

but the caption has an indent, that makes it look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `caption` package offers the `plain` format for this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}


\usepackage[format=plain]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To change this on a figure-to-figure basis:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}


\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{normal caption with hanging indent Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup{format=plain}
    \caption{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{normal caption with hanging indent Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @LukasFun Have a look at my edited answer. Is this what you are looking for?